# How to stop function gathering information before it is completed (Flex & AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I 'try' to develop a program, which is going to ask 10 questions to the user with Flex and ActionScript. (all 10 questions will be asked by 4 different functions which represents 4 basic operations. The answers (in boolean type) will be stored in an array. I just put the plus operation's function here, as all of the functions will be in the same format.

```
protected function ask_plus():Boolean
   {
      var num1:int = math.round(math.random() *100);
      var num2:int = math.round(math.random() *100);
      question.text = num1 + " + " + num2 + "equals = ?";
      var answer:String = new String; //answer will be gotten from the panel where user writes the answer.
      answer = answerInput.text; //i first tried this, but it gets blank answers as false answers.
      if(int(answer) == (num1 + num2))
          return true;
      else
          return false;
   }
```

My question is how can i detect if the user has FINISHED entering his/her input. I tried creating a different function which gets event.Keyboard (keyUp) as input. This is the one which i have tried.

```
protected function check_if(e:Event):String
   {
      trace(event.keyCode);
      while(event.KeyCode != 13) //13 representates the "ENTER" button
      {
           trace(event.keyCode); //until user presses enter, the answer to the question must not be returned.
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 13)
           return answer_input.text;
    }
```

but, the problem here is, i would like to use this check_if in a way that only will work with events from answer_input (textInput) area. What i want is something like that

```
 function a(b = 5)
 {
 trace(b)
 }
```

if I use this function as a(); it will trace 5. But if I use this function as a(10); it will trace 10, instead of 5. Same situation, but with events. It must be something looking like this:

```
 protected function check if(e:answer_input.Event)
 blabla...
```

or something.

Comment: Color me confused. I have no idea what "all 10 questions will be asked by 4 different functions which represents 4 basic operations" means. You ask how to detect if the user has finished entering input; but you have not explained what they of input you expect from the user nor how they are entering it. In a TextInput--or even a NumericStepper--there isn't a generic way to determine that the user has finished entering input.

Comment: re detecting input ending, take a look at LangRef for the input component - it will tell you what events are dispatched by the component. eg: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html#eventSummary - for TextInput (assuming spark version) you could listen to "focusOut" or "enter" events

Comment: sorry for the undetailed question. 4 basic operations means "summation", "subtraction", "multiplying" and "division". The program takes input from a text input (called answerInput). And this will be converted to an integer. The user will press "Enter" (keyCode == 13) when the input is finished. This is how the program is supposed to understand when the input is finished.

Comment: I will check the "enter" event out. This can work.

Comment: it didn't work. the program causes flash player to crash.